# Unable to upload alx file to blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Hello all I am having trouble uploading my blackberry alx file to the blackberry.

I can locate the alx file as you can see here

[image: Blackberry Desktop Manager]

When I click the plus sign it says "pending install". After that I click apply however the alx file cannot be located on the device whatsoever. I also get no error messages or anything. Can someone tell me why this might be?

Comment: As in with a signature key? If so no. I'm trying to use it on my device for debuggin purposes, so I've got a directory with the .alx and cod file in the same directory that as you can see is uploaded to the app screen.

Comment: If you want to use in device then the signature is required.unsigned alx file canot install in to your device.

Comment: So I am assuming that means I need to pay registration etc right? Then add the key under the project menu correct?

Comment: Actually now I have put an alx file on the manager that has the keys attached to it. Still no go. Perhaps my manager is playing up?

Comment: if you are using eclipse sdk then try debug as blackberry device.

Comment: Indeed. It's moaning about keys for my application. If you'd like to put your answer below and I can select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your alx files are not signed. you want to use your application in device the signature is required. thanks.